# Replace paragraph in HTML with new paragraph using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, onload, getelementbyid, appendchild

I am attempting to replace a `p` in my HTML doc with a paragraph created in Javascript. Once the page loads, `two` will be replaced with `t`.

```
var two = document.getElementById("two");

document.onload = function myFunction() {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  var t = document.createTextNode("I am the superior text");
  p.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("p");
  document.two = p;
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jquery? And why don't you just replace the content of the paragraph `p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace the text content of the `#two` element:

```js
var two = document.getElementById("two");

window.onload = function () {
  var t = "I am the superior text";
  two.textContent = t;
};
```

```html
<p id="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

If you use `createTextNode`, then you'll need to use `two.textContent = t.textContent` to get the actual contents of the textNode object.

Note that you can't replace an existing node in the DOM by straight assignment; that's what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace nodes into document directly, you may try innerHTML instead:

```
document.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "I am the superior text";
};
```